# Авто тесты на калькулятор

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

**Добрый день я хочу реализовать Авто тесты на свой калькулятор я могу реализовать только ввод одинарных чисел, а как можно сделать так, чтобы можно программа могла ввести например 10**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace UnitTestProject8
{
    class Avtotest
    {
        [TestCase(5, 5, 10)]

        public void TestPlus(double a, double b, double c)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///C:/Users/DELL-2/Desktop/Calcul2/index.html");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//button[@value='{a}']")).Click(); 
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@value='+']")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//button[@value='{b}']")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@value='=']")).Click();
            IWebElement flashMessage = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//Input[@type='text']"));
            string actual = flashMessage.GetAttribute("value");
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(c, actual);
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/EminMemmedov/dsq6f71w/2/    Код на Калькулятор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразуйте в строку, и нажимайте посимвольно.

```cs
foreach (char ch in a.ToString())
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//button[@value='{ch}']")).Click();
}
```

Comment: String lengths are both 2. Strings differ at index 1.
      Expected: "55"
      But was:  "50"
      ------------^     вот такая ошибка выходит

Comment: @VenDETTA это в результате какого теста?

Comment: этого же теста я там значение поменял   он вводит 50 а дальше не идет

Comment: он как бы дальше ответ не сверяет с актуальным результатом

Comment: Сообщение: 
      Expected: 55.0d
      But was:  "55"

Comment: @VenDETTA Expected: 55.0d But was: "55" - `NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(c, actual.ToString());`

Comment: тоже сомое незнаю почему

Comment: а можно показать в коде

Comment: @VenDETTA наоборот `NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(c.ToString(), actual);`. Вы серьезно не видели эту ошибку, или шутите надо мной? Или вы не знаете, чем отличается `55d` и `"55"`?

Comment: реально не обратил внимание )

Comment: @VenDETTA и что, все равно не работает?

Comment: нет все заработало спасибо